# C - Strange character combinations?

Tags: c, if-statement

I recently came across this piece of code online, [here](https://www.binarytides.com/server-client-example-c-sockets-linux/),
I was unable to read it due to the strange if statement.

```
//Send some data
    if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) &lt; 0)
    {
        puts(&quot;Send failed&quot;);
        return 1;
    }
```

I am specifically referring to the `&lt; 0` following the `send()` function.
I have never seen this use and am having trouble describing it to google.

Can anyone explain this use or link to any resources that may contain more information on it?

Comment: That seems to be a text encoding issue, &lt; is typically a less than symbol (<).

Comment: The `&lt;` is an HTML ["entity"](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) which is rendered as `<` (less than). It is used in places where the `<` would be interpreted as the start of a markup tag. Similarly with the others.

Comment: Your C source got encoded as HTML.  `&lt;` and `&quot;` are [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) for `<` and `"`, respectively.

Comment: Voting to close as non reproducible because it was the result of OP copying and pasting code on the internet with an encoding error

Comment: I am sure the use of `&lt`; and `&quot;` will be commonly reproducible once code was HTML encoded? Perhaps keeping this post open will allow others to find this explanation of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code went through HTML encoding. Replace `&lt;` with `<` and `&quot;` with `"`, and it will immediately make sense.